# Complex $K$-theory of extended powers of a Moore spectrum

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Consider a Moore spectrum $S^n/p$. Has the $K$-theory of the extended powers of $S^n/p$ been computed?

For some context: equivalently, I'd like to have the free $E_\infty$-algebra over $KU$ on the $KU$-module  $KU/p$. If we replace $S^n/p$ by $S^n$, then we do know the answer because of the theory of [power operations](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/knlocal.pdf) over $KU$. Over $H \mathbb{F}_p$, these computations played an important role in the proof of Nishida's nilpotence theorem.

Comment: McClure computes some information about this in the H-infinity book, if I recall correctly. I think he gets the mod p K-theory of an arbitrary extended power of anything, and I remember him being particularly interested in Moore spectra at some point to deal with K-theory mod p^n.

Comment: When $n$ is even I seem to recall that the elements $\theta^{(j)}(px)$ form a regular sequence in the free $\theta$-algebra on $x$ (you can pick off a coefficient which is a unit times $(\theta^{(j-1)} x)^{p}$ for $j > 0$), and so I think the result is the (completed) quotient of $\Bbb Z_p[\theta^{(j)} x]$ by the ideal generated by these elements. I don't know how explicit this can get.

Comment: Thank you for these references, @DylanWilson, and @TylerLawson! These sound exactly like what I was looking for.